# formatting phone numbers using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm newbie for script. I am trying to create a powershell to take all my users in active directory and format all of their phone numbers the same  + 90 (XXX) XXX XX XX

So an example -  `+901111111111`   will turn to  `+90 (111) 111 11 11`

Comment: Are all the phone numbers in the format "+901111111111", or is there a mix of formats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your numbers are  all the same length & pattern, then the `-f` string format operator with a format pattern would do the job. [*grin*] like this ...

```
$InString = '+901111111111'
$OutPattern = '+## (###) ### ## ##'

$OutString = "{0:$OutPattern}" -f [int64]($InString.Trim('+'))
$OutString
```

output = `+90 (111) 111 11 11`

Comment: Clever solution; note that `[int64] $InString` will do; or even: `([int64] $InString).ToString('+## (###) ### ## ##')`

Comment: @mklement0 - hah! i never thot to test if the convert-to-int would handle the leading `+` ... thank you for the info! [*grin*]

Comment: The trim() was a beaut in addition to the string formatting converting [int64] to string

Answer (score 1):

Just in case all numbers have same length this quick solution could solve the problem

```bsh
$input = "+901234567890"

$output = $input.Substring(0,3) +
            " (" +
            $input.Substring(3,3) +
            ") " +
            $input.Substring(6,3) + 
            " " +
            $input.Substring(9,2) + 
            " " +
            $input.Substring(11,2)

# $output value should be "+90 (123) 456 78 90"
```